# Crash when trying to create parameters for a class

Tags: python, class, pygame

When calling a class with the parameters goblin = enemey(100, 410, 64, 64, 450) TypeError: object() takes no parameters . All the code and calls look good, an I cant find the issue.

```
class enemey(object):
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R6E.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('R7E.png'), pygame.image.load('R8E.png'), pygame.image.load('R9E.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('R10E.png'), pygame.image.load('R11E.png')]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'),
                pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'),
                pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'), pygame.image.load('L9E.png'),
                pygame.image.load('L10E.png'), pygame.image.load('L11E.png')]

    def __int__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]  # change variables <- to random for random moving? Make sure to try!

    def draw(self,gameDisplay):
        self.move()
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            gameDisplay.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:  # change to elif to add 3d movement
            gameDisplay.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. `__init__` should be inside the class, but it is not.

Comment: `__int__` is not `__init__`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please review [ask] and maybe take a trip on the [tour].

Comment: Save some typing and make your code more readable: `walk_right = [pygame.image.load(x) for x in ['R1E.png', 'R2E.png', ...]]`.

Comment: Please be more concise in your question, so many code is not necesary at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your constructor is misspelled - it should be `__init__`, not `__int__`. As a result it uses default constructor which accepts no arguments.